# Prevent Android from showing sensible information on multi tasking view

Tags: java, android

I need to hide the content of my application when it goes to the background so sensitive information are not showing up on the android multitasking view.

It's been suggested to use the following line to hide the screen

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

It works fine.

However, this prevents the user from taking screenshot as well which is not an expected behavior for me. I want to let the user take screenshot of the app if they need to. What I don't want is Android to display the latest screen on the multitasking view.

Would it be possible to set the FLAG_SECURE only when the app goes in the background?

Comment: You can exclude the app from the multitasking view.. Is that an option for you?

Comment: That's not an option for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've ended up with this solution which worked the best for us:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if (!hasFocus) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    } else {
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Activity Lifecycle Callbacks. Just call `setVisiblity(View.INVISIBLE)` on the views that you want to hide in the `onPause()` Callback and `setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE)` in `onResume()` Callback.

Comment: I'm not really an android developer, can you point me how to access to root view and apply this setVisibility method?